# category query for pages not working

Tags: wp-query, categories

I have added category support for pages

in functions.php:

```
function add_categories_to_pages() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'add_categories_to_pages' );
```

I created the category 'saloane',
I have pages with category 'saloane' added

in home.php:

```
$saloane_q = new WP_Query ( array('post_type' => 'page', 'category' => 'saloane' ));
if ($saloane_q->have_posts()) :
    while ($saloane_q->have_posts()) : $saloane_q->the_post();
        echo '<div class="f3">';    
        the_post_thumbnail('hr_medium');
        echo '<h2>';
            the_title();
        echo '</h2>';
        the_excerpt();
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

there should be only the pages with category 'saloane' shown, but instead all the pages are shown

I also tried:

```
$saloane_q = new WP_Query ( array('post_type' => 'page', 'category' => 11 ));

$saloane_q = new WP_Query ( array('post_type' => 'page', 'cat' => 11 ));
```

the same result.

with:

```
$saloane_q = new WP_Query ( array('post_type' => 'page', 'category_name' => 'saloane' ));
```

does not display anithyng

if I use it without `post_type` like this:

```
$saloane_q = new WP_Query ( array('category' => 11 ));

$saloane_q = new WP_Query ( array('cat' => 11 ));
```

it displays the  posts.

Answer (score 0):

I just re created the category. Deleted the old category and created a new category with the same name, and now it`s ok.

The pages were imported with the native WordPress import-export plugin, from another wp installation, with the category as well (the category was automatically created when I imported the pages), maybe something went wrong at the import-export process.